# how to replace last digit only in a string using scala

Tags: scala

i have a string "October.29.2009 11:00 a.m."
I want to write a generic code that will replace the time with blank space.
I have tried the below code :

```
{
  val date="October.29.2009 11:00 a.m." //time may be any value
  date.replace("a.m.","").replace("p.m.","")
}
```

Above code can replace am and pm only. I need to replace time also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried splitting the string. Use this:

```
 date.split(" ")
```

The first element of the array returned will give you the date without time.

Comment: but str may be also like "October . 29 . 2009 11 : 00 a.m."

Comment: If that is the case you could use the regex. You could escape regex if there is a certain pattern to which your string is arriving. If it is extremely ambiguous regarding it's pattern then regex is the way to go

Comment: i dont know how to use regex with replace().  :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex like that

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Comment: regex works with replaceAll() or replaceFirst() methods. Not with replace() method

Comment: I have tried following code but gives an error "expecting strin , actualregex"            val str="October.29.2009 11:00 a.m."
  str.replace("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$".r,"")

Comment: replaceall will replace all the digit in string,,, but i want only to replace last time digit.

Answer (score 0):

Is your time always with leading zeros?

```
07:08
```

Then use

```
myString.reverse.substring(countYourCharsAndDigits).reverse
```

Or use a regex that matches the first part, that you are interestet in, and the rest and write it like

```
def dateExtractor(date:String) = {
    val MatchExpression = "('hereTheRegExForTheInterestingPart')('regExForRest)".r
    val MatchExpression(myNewString,rest) = date
    myNewString
}
```

the `(` and `)` is needed for the matchen the `'` not